# Set a report datasource instance at run time

Tags: vb.net, binding, reporting-services, report

I have created a report that is based on a business object - this works great. I am now trying to add a button that renders the report directly to PDF (in a winforms application).
I know what I need to do - in code I am creating a `ReportViewer`, setting the `DataSource`, specifying the report (it's an embedded resource), then rendering the report into a byte array before using `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes` to flush the byte array to disk. One thing I'm hung up on though, is how do I specify the instance of the object properly? I keep getting the "An error has occurred during the report processing" error. In `IntelliTrace` I can see that an exception is thrown "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'IssRep'" (`IssRep` is the dataset name in the report. Here is the code:

```
Dim warning As Warning() = Nothing
Dim streamids As String() = Nothing
Dim mimetype As String = Nothing
Dim encoding As String = Nothing
Dim extension As String = Nothing

Dim viewer As New ReportViewer
Dim bs As New BindingSource
bs.DataSource = issuedet
Dim rds As New ReportDataSource
rds.Value = bs


viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
viewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "FRSFE.SR.rdlc"

Dim pdfbytes As Byte()
Try
    pdfbytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", Nothing, mimetype, encoding, extension, streamids, warning)
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Shared\FRS\SR.PDF", pdfbytes)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I'm pretty sure whatever I'm stuck on is pretty simple as I'm very rusty on .NET but I just can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `rds.Name = "IssRep"` before adding it to `viewer.LocalReport.DataSources`.